# useRef returns undefined after clicking the react-router NavLink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom, use-ref

I'm referencing an element in a hook that measures the elements dimensions. When I first load the page. The element reference number logs undefined, but then defines itself.

The dimensions are used to position an absolutely positioned element into the center. When the page first loads, the element is centered. As the window size is changed, the element remains centered.

However, when I click a NavLink from react-dom-router and click back to the home page where the element reference belongs, the reference logs as undefined without later defining it self. The element is not centered until I resize the page.

My setup is:

- React v18.2.0
- react-dom-router v6.3.0
- styled-components v5.3.5

My intuition tells me that it's something to do with the useLayoutEffect dependency array..

But any suggestions and help on how to fix this bug would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useWindowDimensions } from "../services/hooks/useWindowDimensions";
import { useGetElementDimensions } from "../services/hooks/useElementDimensions";
import {
  HeroImage,
  HomeContainer,
  TextContainer,
  TextContainerOverlay,
  TextDescription,
} from "../components/StyledElements/HomeStyles.js";

const Home = () => {
  const textRef = useRef();
  const { width: windowWidth, height: windowHeight } = useWindowDimensions();
  const { width:textWidth, height: textHeight } = useGetElementDimensions(textRef)

  console.log(textRef);

  return (
    <HomeContainer height={`${windowHeight - 85}px`}>
      <HeroImage
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587574293340-e0011c4e8ecf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1932&q=80"
        alt="landingImage"
      />
      <TextContainer
        ref={textRef}
        left={`${(windowWidth - textWidth) / 2}px`}
        top={`${((windowHeight - textHeight) / 2) - 42}px`}
      >
        <TextDescription>
          Welcome to Pastasauce, a restaurant of italian cuisine focusing
          entirely on pasta. On the food selection screen you will be able to
          add what you want from the menu and it will be ready for you when you
          arrive at the restaurant.
        </TextDescription>
        <TextContainerOverlay></TextContainerOverlay>
      </TextContainer>
    </HomeContainer>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The following is the custom hook, that I'm using for getting the elements dimensions.

```js
import { useCallback, useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useGetElementDimensions = (ref) => {

  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  const handleResize = useCallback(() => {
    setWidth(ref.current.offsetWidth)
    setHeight(ref.current.offsetHeight)
  }, [ref]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('load', handleResize);
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('load', handleResize)
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    }
  }, [ref, handleResize])

  return {width, height}
}
```

Comment: Aside from the problem you can do the whole centering using css way easier than using js. Just use `left: 50%; top: 50%;` and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug.

It is undefined because you are assigning the reference of a dom element thats in the same component, which means it has to be mounted first to get a value.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```
    const Home = () => {
      const textRef = useRef(); // undefined
...
      const { width:textWidth, height: textHeight } = useGetElementDimensions(textRef) // still undefined
    
      console.log(textRef); // says undefined
    
      return (
...       <TextContainer
            ref={textRef} // gets value AFTER mount
            left={`${(windowWidth - textWidth) / 2}px`}
            top={`${((windowHeight - textHeight) / 2) - 42}px`}
          >
...
      );
```

EDIT:

Possible solution for your case after wrapping your function inside `useLayoutEffect`: [Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=3&pln=38&pc=29#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-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-fBg0yagIFVJRRGiJmgi7YBmBadoXZrMALfSLQ4AaGtDTFLGIHEOBiA2DBRizgYkAUOB2heEDgBaFo4DWsUUDWjZnwgUPmb9ECLARYvS8+53fmfKC4D2fBmYkN34A9Cuq7Ff5xGjrGoA7wepCgmsS-wJuUHVYBmmZ+BU-t9JHc1Jm7N0VX+kGYZRh13WVeqEoyhzJpWg6Glj9Fu+JagR+oDador95V-b7ORzH-Y+jl37lB1qeCgVxuCgjuOIJUaNWaJDcGwIAA)

```
export const useUpdateElementDimensions = (ref, onResize) => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {    
    const resize = () => {
      onResize(ref.current.offsetWidth, ref.current.offsetHeight);
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', resize);
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('load', resize)
      window.removeEventListener('resize', resize)
    }
  }, [ref, onResize]);
} 

const Home = () => {
  const textRef = useRef();
  const { width: windowWidth, height: windowHeight } = useWindowDimensions();
  
  const onResize = (w, h) => {
    textRef.current.left = windowWidth - w / 2;
    textRef.current.top = windowHeight - h / 2 - 42;
  }

  useUpdateElementDimensions(textRef,onResize)
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the comment, if I understood you and the docs correctly, part of the issue is that I'm using a ref nested as a child within the Home parent component. In the docs they mention ref forwarding and callbacks, Ref forwarding looks appropriate.. Do you have a suggestion as to how to ensure ref is defined?

Comment: I would first try to wrap the hooks using the ref in `useLayoutEffect` , eg: 
```useLayoutGetElementDimensions = useLayoutEffect(useGetElementDimensions, ... )```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Mike, so something like this in the rendering page...
```js

const textRef = useRef();

const { width: windowWidth, height: windowHeight } = useWindowDimensions();

const elementDimensions = useLayoutEffect(useElementDimensions(textRef), [])

const { width: textWidth, height: textHeight } = elementDimensions

console.log(textRef);
```

Comment: Hey @Lauro235, I have updated my original answer with an example. Sorry that the first suggestion wasnt clear. Not sure that it works as you expected, but the function will only run when you have reference. I do not think that it is worth adding `ref` as a dependency of `useLayoutEffect` though, but not sure about your future ideas

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for your code suggestions. I'm going to leave it for now.. I couldn't fix the React render issue, and it might be better to move on and focus on something else. Still would like to understand how to get a useLayoutEffect to persist after clicking a NavLink.. Some other day..

Comment: I guess navigation re-renders the component and effect does not run again? It can be solved as well. If you want, create a github public repository where you introduce these issues with a codebase or do it on a website (codepen or something similar) so I can take a look at it and help. Cheers mate, good luck

Comment: Hi Mike, I made a sandbox today with my initial code that I never fully understood why it was behaving the way it was.. Here it is.. https://codesandbox.io/s/centering-an-absolutely-positioned-element-with-js-b7i8i0?file=/src/pages/FoodSelection/index.js

And thanks again man

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247998/discussion-between-lauro235-and-imike).